# How to get the minimum result of invoking a function on an array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a function `foo(x,y)` that returns an int. My data set is an array of arrays like `a = [[1], [2,3], [4]]`. I want to perform foo but for each index of `a`, I only want the minimum value if the array has more than one element. 
So I want to calculate `foo(1, 1` `foo(1,4)` and the minimum between `foo(1,2)`  `foo(1,3)`.

So if `foo(1,2)` is lower my calculation for the first index of `a` is `foo(1,1) foo(1,2) foo(1,4)` and push that total to some array `b`. I want to do this for each element in `a` and every element in `a` could possibly have more than one element

Comment: Please include some real code, including actual inputs and expected outputs. It's very difficult to tell what you're talking about. What is `foo(1,1)`? Where does the first `1` come from? If it isn't part of your inputs, why include it in your example at all?

Comment: For `a = [[1], [2,3], [4]]`, do you want `a.map { |b| b.min } #=> [1,2,4]` (which can be written more succinctly as  `a.map(&:min)`)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but basically the array is going through itself and performing foo on itself and each of its elements. if a was just a single dimensional array `a = [1,2,3]`, it would kind of look like

`for i in 0...a.length  
    for j in 0...a.length  
        b.push ( foo(a[i],a[j] )  
    end  
end`  
  
however the problem differs once it becomes 2 dimensional. for each a[i] and a[j], i want only push the minimum value of foo(a[i],a[j])

Comment: Rather than add a comment to explain further, add that information to the question itself where everyone knows to look for it. Don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags, but put the information where you would have added it initially. We can see what's changed if we need to.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the included links, along with "[mcve]", which specifies how to create a "it doesn't work" question. A description of your code is not nearly as useful as the minimal code that demonstrates the problem. Describing it makes us imagine what you've done, and we have nearly unlimited ability to imagine; Show us the minimum code demonstrating the problem and we all work from the same place.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = a.map{|arr| arr.map{|value| foo(1, value) }.min }
```

For each inner array value it does `foo(1,value)` and then selects the minimum result.  In the case of only one value, only one number is calculated, of course.

It's not clear what the "1" represents in your example (the first argument of `foo`)

Comment: sorry. the 1 represented the value in  `a[0]`. So for each element in a it will `foo(a[0], a[element])`. if a[element] is more than one element it needs to choose  the min `foo(a[0], a[element[i] ])`. Then it goes a[1] and so on.

Comment: You say "and then it goes a[1] and so on" but what if `a[1]`itself has more than one element (like your example)?   element 1 is`a[2,3]` so when we match that as the "first" argument for foo, do we want to do `foo(2,4)` and `foo(3.4)` and return the minimum?  What happens if element `x` has three values and element `y` has two values, how do you want to handle it when you get to testing `foo(x, y)` ?

Comment: In any case, has been suggested, you should add any clarifications to the main question.